# Potentially unusual variant of least squares minimization

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, least-squares, binary-programming

I've been digging through the optimization literature for a solution to a problem like this, but have been coming up empty.

Suppose you have a modifiable matrix L (itself just a collection of vectors in a sample) and modifiable coefficients $\beta$. Given a set of objective vectors $O$, with each vector called $O_k$, is there a closed form for the solution to:

$$\arg \min_{L,\beta} \sum_k \| L\cdot\beta - O_k \|_2$$

particularly if $O_k$ is continuous and $L$ is restricted to binary?

I'm familiar with the derivation for ordinary linear least squares in matrix form, but haven't yet thought of a way to analytically solve this problem. Given it appears nonlinear I'm kind of expecting there won't be such an analytic solution, but I thought I would query the collective expertise of this site before giving up.

---

P.S. I've tagged it as both "convex optimization" and "nonlinear optimization" because while I'm pretty sure it's the latter given the multiplied variables in the form of $L$ and $\beta$, I'm not 100% certain whether it will be convex or not.

Comment: Is $\beta$ also continuous like $L$, or is it binary? If it is binary, it is probably best to consider $L\beta$ as a single integer vector $x$ to begin with, and then find solutions to $x=L\beta$ after solving $\text{argmin}_{x}\sum_{k}\lVert x-O_k\rVert_2$. Otherwise, the same, but $x$ is continuous.

Comment: $\beta$ is continuous, while L is restricted to binary.

Comment: Please define "binary". $\{\pm 1\}$ or $\{0,1\}$?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is equivalent to

$$\arg \min_{x,L,\beta} \left\{ \sum_k\lVert x-O_k\rVert_2:x=L\beta \right\}$$

A relaxation to that problem is

$$\arg\min_{x} \left\{\sum_k\lVert x-O_k\rVert_2\right\}$$

and a necessary condition for a minimum $x^*$ is that

$$\nabla\sum_k\lVert x^*-O_k\rVert_2=\frac{\sum_{k}(x^*-O_k)}{\lVert x^*-O_k\rVert_2}=\boldsymbol 0$$

which gives the solution $x^*=\frac{1}{K}\sum_k{O_k}$.

Notice that $L=I$ and $\beta=x=\frac{1}{K}\sum_k{O_k}$ solves the original unrelaxed problem with the same objective value. So this is optimal.